# Mongo DB Time Series Performance on just secondary Index

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, indexing, time-series

I am building a mongoose model to store survey response data. There are, however, different types of surveys with different response rates. One type of survey has frequent answers (perhaps every few seconds) and data is normally queried in chunks of time, eg from startDate to endDate of the response. However, some surveys only get responses maybe a 20 times a month, and sometimes I would want to get all the data for that survey just based on the survey_id, and, not using any time field constraints.

So my question is, do secondary indexes on time series collections work as well as they would on a non-time series collection?

My model looks like this:

```
const responseSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    metaData: {
      type: new mongoose.Schema({
        survey_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "survey", required: true },
      }),
      required: true,
    },
    createdAt: Date,
    answers: { type: Map, of: mongoose.Mixed },
  },
  {
    timeseries: {
      timeField: "createdAt",
      metaField: "metaData",
      granularity: "seconds",
    },
  }
);
responseSchema.plugin(ts);
responseSchema.index({ "metaData.survey_id": 1, "createdAt": 1  });
```

I would expect normal querys using the createdAt field as filters to work well, but what if I only query by survey_id and don't use the time field. Will that still work well? or do I get performance degradation by not using the time field with a time series collection.

querys of this collection will always be based on the survey_id

Comment: You can create indexes on any other fields (single or compound indexes) and these would get applied when used with queries appropriately. You can check/verify the index usage by generating a Query Plan , using the explain method.

Comment: so my proposed index would work just as well on a time series collection as it would on a non-time series collection? @prasad_

Comment: I believe so. There is no evidence that it wont work or wont work well. As always, verify yourself about it in the query plan.